# Dispatch different argument types to a map of functions

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, function-pointers

Problem: I get a command ID(int) and a data buffer (bytes), and I want to invoke a function based on this ID. Each ID has an associated user-defined data type(known at compile time) and the incoming data bytes conform to this data type. The function also needs to work with a known internal data pointer that is initialized when the program starts (in the constructor perhaps)

Idea: I intend to make a function dispatcher that can take different types of arguments. Given having multiple function signatures mapped in a container is not feasible, I tried to make my function dispatcher a map of std::functions that take `BaseArgs*` as a common pointer.

Each of my function callbacks now internally casts to different `DerivedArgs` structs.

Each `DerivedArg` consists of a pointer to a member of `GiantFoo` (also known at compile time) and an incoming data buffer that can be one of `DataFooN`. For example, `DerivedArgs0` points to `foo0` member of `GiantFoo` and a pointer to `DataFoo0`.

Question: In main, I only know the `id` of the function pointer to invoke it. I still need to cast the incoming data_buffer to an appropriate `DataFoo1` type before invoking the function.
Do I need another map of IDs to instantiated DerivedArgs (not sure if I can make such a container given they're different types)? Or is there a better way?

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>

struct MinorFoo0
{
    int a;
};

struct MinorFoo1
{
    int a;
};

struct GiantFoo
{
    MinorFoo0 foo0;
    MinorFoo1 foo1;
};

GiantFoo giant_foo;

struct DataFoo0
{
    int x;
};

struct DataFoo1
{
    int x;
};

struct BaseArgs
{
    uintptr_t giantfoo_ptr;
    virtual ~BaseArgs() = default;
};

struct DerivedArgs0 : BaseArgs
{
    DataFoo0* foo0;

    DerivedArgs0() {
        this->giantfoo_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&giant_foo.foo0);
    }
};

struct DerivedArgs1 : BaseArgs
{
    DataFoo1* foo1;

    DerivedArgs1() {
        this->giantfoo_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&giant_foo.foo1);
    }
};

using MyFnPtr = std::function<int(BaseArgs*)>;

int foo0_cb(BaseArgs* args)
{
    auto foo0_arg = dynamic_cast<DerivedArgs0*>(args);
    return 0;
}

int foo1_cb(BaseArgs*)
{
    return 0;
}

enum MyFnEnums
{
    FOO_0 = 0,
    FOO_1 = 1
};

std::unordered_map<int, MyFnPtr> mymap {
    {FOO_0, foo0_cb},
    {FOO_1, foo1_cb}
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t data_buffer[100] = {};
    int id = 0;
    void* data = &data_buffer;

    // How to fit data to a DerivedArgsN and pass to mymap?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is better you start with WHAT you want to achieve.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. What is the motivation of all this?

Comment: using ```dynamic_cast``` you can loop on all ```mymap``` to find one that manages your type (O(N) process).
If you have a way to create an order on your data type (perhaps through a unique Id for each ```DerivedArgs``` type, you may use an ordered map in O(log(N)).
I'm not sure if it's clear enough...

Comment: @PepijnKramer I get a command id and some data, and I want to invoke a function based on this ID. Each ID has an associated data type and the incoming data conforms to this data type.

Comment: Ok I added a problem statement, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Do you  know the ID's at compile time?

Comment: Yes, IDs and the data type associated with it is known at compile time.

Comment: And the data enters as a buffer of bytes? Or already as known datatypes

Comment: Buffer of bytes yes, its coming over network, hence the uint_t buffer in the example.

Comment: So your function should be of the form `void(const uint8_t* /*, std::size_t&*/ )`

Comment: That's fair, I will eventually need to transform it to a DerivedArgs because the buffer needs to be cast to the appropriate type. DerivedArgs also points to an internal struct (GiantFoo). So I guess there needs to be a translation layer that converts these bytes to DerivedArgs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the server side of RPC.  And while there's a myriad of solutions, the basic problem boils down to deciding what to call, and then transforming the arguments to the appropriate call.  And you know what all of them are at compile-time.  So let's treat it that way

```cpp
using DispatchFunction = std::function<int(uint8_t*, size_t)>;

const uint32_t FUNC_ID1 = 1;
int actualWork1(const Type1& argument) {
    // Do stuff!
    return 0;
}

const uint32_t FUNC_ID2 = 2;
int actualWork2(const uint32_t arg1, const double arg2) {
    // Do other stuff!
    return -1;  // Return error!
}

void doVariousThings(){
    // Set up our map of stuff
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, DispatchFunction> dispatcher = {
        { FUNC_ID1, [](uint8_t* data_ptr, size_t data_size) -> int {
            // Deserialize the data to the needed type
            Type1 currentArg = decodeFor_actualWork1(data_ptr, data_size);  // Or make this a constructor of Type1
            return actualWork1(currentArg);
        };
        },  // End of first map entry
        { FUNC_ID2, [](uint8_t* data_ptr, size_t data_size) -> int {
            // Deserialize the data to the needed TWO types
            uint32_t firstArg{};
            double secondArg{};
            bool failureToTranslate = decodeFor_actualWork2(data_ptr, data_size, firstArg, secondArg); // Assume signature is (uint8_t*, size_t, uint32_t&, double&)
            // Check for failure to translate here, but for the example, just assume it worked
            
            return actualWork2(firstArg, secondArg);
        };
        },  // End of second map entry
    };
    
    // Now just take the ID from the stream and call the functional
    vector<uint8_t> buffer = stream.recv()  // get the data, however you get it
    uint32_t ID = *((uint32_t*)buffer.data());
    // Call the needed function
    uint8_t* data_ptr = buffer.data() + sizeof(uint32_t);   // past the ID header
    size_t data_size = buffer.size() - sizeof(uint32_t);    // size without header
    int result_of_function_call = dispatcher[ID](data_ptr, data_size);
    
    return;
}
```

There's a couple more things you could wrap up there to be cleaner (type translation should account for failures for example, probably an `enum` or `enum class` for the IDs), but this is the general idea.  Your common format is your actual datastream.  Extract the ID of what you're calling, and pass the data into the `DispatchFunction` to translate back into your arguments and call your actual destination function.  If you need to capture something from the context (like if all of this is in a class, capturing `this`), capture it into the lambdas there.  Then you can even call member functions no problem.

You don't even need any classes, just `std::function` and you're done.  You can be more clever, and use `std::bind` if you want to, but I think this demonstrates the basics with no extras.

Classes are great, and sublclassing is very useful, but you don't *need* it for this, and I don't think it adds clarity here.

Comment: Thanks. This makes the design simpler. For me the takeaway here is that the map holds the incoming buffer and its size. Then comes a translation layer that transforms data and any class members into a type/s that the eventual function understands. I was stuck at this step. In your example the translation layer does the work. If I have a hundred commands then I have 100 such translation functions, and I didn't know of a clean way to do that.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  Keep in mind that above we're state-less so even function pointers for the `DispatchFunction` could work, but as soon as you add state, captures, etc, the `std::function` and lambda is easier.  In one way it's a series of [Trampoline Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) or very close to it, calling a member or whatever that does the translation to the real task.  The key here is not needing a "god class" that knows how to _dispatch_ ALL handlers, just IDs.  If this answers your question, please hit the "check" here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify a bit, according to my understanding of the question.
Fill free to tell me if I misunderstood, I will remove my answer.

I propose this.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum MyFnEnums { FOO_0 = 0, FOO_1 = 1 };

struct BaseArgs {
    MyFnEnums e;
    BaseArgs(const MyFnEnums a) : e(a){};
    virtual ~BaseArgs() = default;
};

struct DerivedArgs0 : BaseArgs {
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> data_buffer;
    DerivedArgs0() : BaseArgs(MyFnEnums::FOO_0){};
};
struct DerivedArgs1 : BaseArgs {
    int data = 0;
    DerivedArgs1() : BaseArgs(MyFnEnums::FOO_1){};
};

using MyFnPtr = std::function<int(BaseArgs*)>;

int foo0_cb(BaseArgs* args) {
    auto foo0_arg = dynamic_cast<DerivedArgs0*>(args);
    if (foo0_arg != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "foo0 " << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << foo0_arg->data_buffer[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "foo0: wrong arg type" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int foo1_cb(BaseArgs* args) {
    auto foo1_arg = dynamic_cast<DerivedArgs1*>(args);
    if (foo1_arg != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "foo1: " << foo1_arg->data << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "foo1: wrong arg type" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

std::map<MyFnEnums, MyFnPtr> mymap{{FOO_0, foo0_cb}, {FOO_1, foo1_cb}};

int main() {
    DerivedArgs0 a0;
    a0.data_buffer = {
        'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0,
    };
    DerivedArgs1 a1;
    a1.data = 42;

    mymap[FOO_0](&a0);
    mymap[FOO_1](&a1);
    mymap[FOO_0](&a1);
    mymap[FOO_1](&a0);

    return 0;
}
```

Actual arguments are wrapped into child `DerivedArgsN` of `BaseArgs`.
Inside each function, I try the `dynamic_cast` and propose a fallback if the argument is not of the right type.
Functions are stored in an ordered `map` with your `enum` as key.
I call the function by passing a pointer to the arg.
[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/ssG1rKTPj)
Syntax can be improved by passing references but you will still need pointer inside the function, so that the ```dynamic_cast`` wan't throw:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum MyFnEnums { FOO_0 = 0, FOO_1 = 1 };

struct BaseArgs {
    MyFnEnums e;
    BaseArgs(const MyFnEnums a) : e(a){};
    virtual ~BaseArgs() = default;
};

struct DerivedArgs0 : BaseArgs {
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> data_buffer;
    DerivedArgs0() : BaseArgs(MyFnEnums::FOO_0){};
};
struct DerivedArgs1 : BaseArgs {
    int data = 0;
    DerivedArgs1() : BaseArgs(MyFnEnums::FOO_1){};
};

using MyFnPtr = std::function<int(BaseArgs&)>;

int foo0_cb(BaseArgs& args) {
    auto foo0_arg = dynamic_cast<DerivedArgs0*>(&args);
    if (foo0_arg != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "foo0 " << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << foo0_arg->data_buffer[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "foo0: wrong arg type" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int foo1_cb(BaseArgs& args) {
    auto foo1_arg = dynamic_cast<DerivedArgs1*>(&args);
    if (foo1_arg != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "foo1: " << foo1_arg->data << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "foo1: wrong arg type" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

std::map<MyFnEnums, MyFnPtr> mymap{{FOO_0, foo0_cb}, {FOO_1, foo1_cb}};

int main() {
    DerivedArgs0 a0;
    a0.data_buffer = {
        'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0,
    };
    DerivedArgs1 a1;
    a1.data = 42;

    mymap[FOO_0](a0);
    mymap[FOO_1](a1);
    mymap[FOO_0](a1);
    mymap[FOO_1](a0);

    return 0;
}
```

Yet, according to what you actually want to achieve, it's not necessarily the best design. This answers only the question, "how to emulate storing of functions with different argument types into a map".